# c# Exceptions Not Stopping at Location of exception Debugging Problem

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2022

my c# forms app (Vs 2022) in debug mode is just now beginning to show errors in weird places like String.Manipulation.cs.  I know the error occurred in my app. But it shows it in some predefined code. I tried to clean and re-open the project, and recompile. But the debug behavior persists. The code below represents a section of the predefined code where it points.

The specific line is

> "throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName,message);"

the error details;

> "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException   HResult=0x80131502
> Message=startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. (Parameter
> 'startIndex')   Source=System.Private.CoreLib   StackTrace:    at
> System.String.ThrowSubstringArgumentOutOfRange(Int32 startIndex, Int32
> length) in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs:line
> 1878    at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex) in
> /*/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs:line
> 1837    at cabinetry.frmMain.ProcessScan() in
> C:\Users\doug\source\cabinetry\cabinetry\frmMain.cs:line 487    at
> cabinetry.frmMain.ScannerTime_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
> C:\Users\doug\source\cabinetry\cabinetry\frmMain.cs:line 558    at
> System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr
> wparam, IntPtr lparam)    at Interop.User32.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(UIntPtr
> dwComponentID, msoloop uReason, Void* pvLoopData)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(msoloop
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(msoloop
> reason, ApplicationContext context)    at cabinetry.Program.Main() in
> C:\Users\doug\source\cabinetry\cabinetry\Program.cs:line 14

```
      [DoesNotReturn]
       private void ThrowSubstringArgumentOutOfRange(int startIndex, int length)
       {
           (string paramName, string message) =
               startIndex < 0 ? (nameof(startIndex), SR.ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndex) :
               startIndex > Length ? (nameof(startIndex), SR.ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndexLargerThanLength) :
               length < 0 ? (nameof(length), SR.ArgumentOutOfRange_NegativeLength) :
               (nameof(length), SR.ArgumentOutOfRange_IndexLength);

           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, message);
       }

       private string InternalSubString(int startIndex, int length)
       {
           Debug.Assert(startIndex >= 0 && startIndex <= this.Length, "StartIndex is out of range!");
           Debug.Assert(length >= 0 && startIndex <= this.Length - length, "length is out of range!");

           string result = FastAllocateString(length);

           Buffer.Memmove(
               elementCount: (uint)result.Length, // derefing Length now allows JIT to prove 'result' not null below
               destination: ref result._firstChar,
               source: ref Unsafe.Add(ref _firstChar, (nint)(uint)startIndex /* force zero-extension */));

           return result;
```

Comment: Here's where your problem is `C:\Users\doug\source\cabinetry\cabinetry\frmMain.cs:line 487 at cabinetry.frmMain.ScannerTime_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) `

Comment: yes i get that but the debugger doesn't stop there it throws up this String.Manipulation.CS and shows me the error at that spot. This is not my code it is some underlying system code.

Comment: the code it is showing has nothing to do with frmMain.cs line 487

Comment: Most likely you disabled "my code only" option in "debugging" section for some reason... (Note that "predefined" is very strange word to use for .Net source code... )

Comment: thank you that fixed it. I did not change that option.

Comment: @zapdbf Hi zapdbf, I posted an answer with common solutions. For this situation, Alexei is correct, but when you encounter strange behaviour of VS Tools next time, you can consider to reset the settings to make it normal. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your situation:

**Form1.cs**

```
namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AddControls();
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormsApp2
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        private void AddControls()
        {
            // Create text box
            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Location = new Point(50, 50);
            this.Controls.Add(textBox);

            // create button
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "add input";
            button.Location = new Point(50, 80);
            button.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                textBox.Text = "xxx"; // something

                this.Controls.Add(button);
                int argumentValue = -1;
                int minimumValue = 0;
                int maximumValue = 100;

                if (argumentValue < minimumValue || argumentValue > maximumValue)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("argumentValue", argumentValue,
                        $"Parameter must between {minimumValue} and {maximumValue}.");
                }
            };

            this.Controls.Add(button);
        }
        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Text = "Form1";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

If I start debugging and click the button I created, click step into, I will jump in the external code(Not my code):

[image]

## **As Alexei metioned, you just need to select "Enable Just My Code" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General:**

[image]

[image]

### **By the way, "Enable Just My Code" is the default settings, so next time if you encounter some situations that something is normal before but become strange now, you can consider to reset the entire settings via these(In the way, you don't need to know which setting cause the issue, just reset entire settings.):**

Reset environment settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

turn off synchronized settings on a particular computer(This step is to prevent settings override):

[image]][8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AiKm.png)

[image]